# How Do I recover data from a dropped Table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, flashback

I accidentally dropped a table, and I recovered it with flashback statement and recycle bin information:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==$0" TO BEFORE DROP;
```

But when I made it a `select * from XXX` it was empty. 
Is there a way to recover the `rows/information/data` from that table?

OR, Does flashback recover all rows? maybe it's empty because it didn't have nothing at the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `FLASHBACK TABLE "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==$0" TO TIMESTAMP Clause`?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmflash.htm#BRADV8702

`FLASHBACK` should recover the rows. This is its main purpose.

Comment: No, I haven't, but I think it was enough with "TO BEFORE DROP" right?

do you know if I use that, it recovers all information? maybe the table was originally empty, and that's why I don't see nothing now

Comment: `XXX` is your orginal table name?

Comment: It is very possible that it was empty. But maybe someone removed the data before for example using `DELETE`. This is why I would just check the `FLASHBACK TABLE XXX TO TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-17 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');`

Comment: but I made a Flashback table and the Recycle bin [XXXX = "BIN$9Od2TS4UJZOnPgQ34HQArn3Q==$0"] doesn't exist anymore, what can I do?

Comment: @PabloGlez you're SOL if you don't have offline backups.

Comment: Unless I drop it again and then I can make that, but I'm not sure, should I?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know, what it "SOL"?

Comment: shit out of luck (not comparable)
(idiomatic) Completely out of luck; in unfortunate circumstances such that all options for achieving one's goal are exhausted;

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit_out_of_luck

Comment: @PabloGlez As `XXX` enter your table name. Flashback is not only for droped table. You can event flashback the whole database to given timestamp.

Comment: THAAAANK YOU! IT WORKED! I only had to enables the row movement!

Answer (score 0):

Flashback recovers all fields and records. If it is empty, then it most probably did not had anything before it was dropped.